# See original image tag from Kubernetes annotations / docker labels / docker configuration

Tags: docker, kubernetes

## Problem

I am unable to determine the original image tag (and so the image *version*) on a running container in Kubernetes.

## Description

#### Pure Docker:

---

When running a container in pure docker and the inspecting the container, I can always view the image tag. For example, when starting a container running `ubuntu:18.04` and then inspecting it (using `docker inspect`) I see the following output (hugely shortened for brevity):

```
[
    {
        "Id": "e4109d8d4a3835f92629732d9dcb0967c16f9a716c6bbda8edf3a4423d714d01",
        "Image": "sha256:2eb2d388e1a255c98029f40d6d7f8029fb13f1030abc8f11ccacbca686a8dc12",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "e4109d8d4a38",
            "Env": ["PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"],
            "Image": "ubuntu:18.04",
            "Labels": {}
        }
    }
]
```

Here I can see that `.Config.Image` shows my original image + tag (`ubuntu:18.04`).

#### Kubernetes:

---

When pulling the same image into a Kubernetes cluster, it seems that Kubernetes always uses the digest when it creates the running container. Here is an example from a test pod also using `ubuntu:18.04`, showing output from `kubectl desribe pod...`

```
  Normal  Scheduled  109s  default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/test-697b599788-t9xp9 to docker-desktop
  Normal  Pulling    108s  kubelet, docker-desktop  Pulling image "ubuntu:18.04"
  Normal  Pulled     104s  kubelet, docker-desktop  Successfully pulled image "ubuntu:18.04"
  Normal  Created    104s  kubelet, docker-desktop  Created container ubuntu
  Normal  Started    103s  kubelet, docker-desktop  Started container ubuntu
```

Above, the image that has been pulled is the image that is described in my pod specification (namely, `ubuntu:18.04`). So far, so good.

When I inspect the container from the docker API (via the mounted socket),  `.Config.Image` is showing the digest, not the original tag. I have again amended the output for brevity:

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock https://localhost/container/99a29951d0b385875c54e586497dbbf1d3c6266bfc10351d0c75e6774394c682/json
{
  "Id": "99a29951d0b385875c54e586497dbbf1d3c6266bfc10351d0c75e6774394c682",
  "Image": "sha256:1e4467b07108685c38297025797890f0492c4ec509212e2e4b4822d367fe6bc8",
  "Config": {
    "Hostname": "test-7787dcf6d-h58rn",
    "Env": [
      "KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443",
      "KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443",
      "KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.96.0.1:443",
      "KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.96.0.1:443",
      "KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp",
      "KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443",
      "KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.96.0.1",
      "KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.96.0.1",
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Image": "ubuntu@sha256:5d1d5407f353843ecf8b16524bc5565aa332e9e6a1297c73a92d3e754b8a636d",
    "Labels": {
      "annotation.io.kubernetes.container.hash": "3ee6fba4",
      "annotation.io.kubernetes.container.restartCount": "0",
      "annotation.io.kubernetes.container.terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
      "annotation.io.kubernetes.container.terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
      "annotation.io.kubernetes.pod.terminationGracePeriod": "30",
      "io.kubernetes.container.logpath": "/var/log/pods/default_test-7787dcf6d-h58rn_cf601af0-84fe-4df7-8126-736189b6f7a6/ubuntu/0.log",
      "io.kubernetes.container.name": "ubuntu",
      "io.kubernetes.docker.type": "container",
      "io.kubernetes.pod.name": "test-7787dcf6d-h58rn",
      "io.kubernetes.pod.namespace": "default",
      "io.kubernetes.pod.uid": "cf601af0-84fe-4df7-8126-736189b6f7a6",
      "io.kubernetes.sandbox.id": "cf212829401e97a4ed65fb7707d912be676f775a895977ef0c9c62bb28fec74f"
    }
  }
}
```

If I grep the complete output, at no point do I find the label "18.04".  I understand the mutability aspect, and that using the digest is in line with best practice, but I am curious to know if there is a way to get my original tag.

If Kubernetes is pulling the digest of the image with the tag `18.04`, is there an option to annotate the container with the original image tag, so that it becomes available in the docker API (in `.Labels` or `.Env`), or in short is there any way that the docker API can determine the original image tag, and thus the actual version of ubuntu (or any other application type)?

Comment: What is the use case? Is there a specific reason why you need to run docker commands to get this information?

Comment: I am using logspout, deployed as a daemonset across the Kubernetes cluster. This collects logs and forwards them to a central logging service, and the running container has the docker socket mounted as a volume. Before sending the logs on, logspout can prefix the message with important info (such as host, docker container ID, etc). What we would like to see as part of this prefix is the version of the container, pulled from the image tag.

Comment: Maybe you could try to define manually an [environment variable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/) inside your container with your image tag? Have you tried that? Or that won't work in your situation?